# Unnecessary padding in react component when iterate second time?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

This is my react component

```
return (
        <div>
         {this.props.data.map(({name,info,total_star,total_user,website,image }, index) => 
            <div key={index}>
                <div  className="card border-primary">
                    <div className="card-body">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-6">
                                <img src={image} className="img-resonsive card-image"></img>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-md-6">
                                <table className="table table-responsive">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{index+1}</td><td className="channelName">{name}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>URL</td><td><Link to="" className="card-link">{website}</Link></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <img src="https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/fourthpillar-static/media/star.png" style={{width:"25px",height:"25px"}}></img>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>  
                                            <h1 style={{textAlign:"left",float:"left" }}>{total_star/total_user}</h1>
                                            <h6 style={{textAlign:"left",float:"left",paddingTop:"30px"}}>
                                                /10
                                            </h6>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Votes</td><td>{total_user}</td>
                                    </tr>

                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br></br>
            </div>
            )
```

And this is my app.css file

```
.card{
    border:1px solid black!important;

}
.img-responsive.img-center {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
.channelName{
    font-style: bold!important;
    font-size: 30px!important;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #fe4902;
}

.card-image{
    width:90%;
    height:200px; 

}
```

The map function iterate 10 times. But when it iterate from second time I got unnecessary left padding between td items of table. I am not able to figure out whether it is css issue, react issue or bootstrap issue. Please help me figure out.Please see picture for understanding.
[image]

Comment: Just for clarification, should the first one have less space, or should the second one have more?

Comment: Second one have less space. First one is perfect as I want.